# How to use Products.csvreplicata 1.1.7 with Products.PressRoom to export PressContacts in Plone 4.1

Tags: python, plone

How to use Products.csvreplicata 1.1.7 with Products.PressRoom 3.18 to export PressContacts to csv in Plone 4.1? Or is there any other product to import/export all the PressRoom contacts into csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Site setup / CSV Replicata tool, and select PressRoom content(s) as exportable (and then select the schemata you want to be considered during import/export).

Comment: Thanks buddy ! It was cooool :)